# Is it possible to pick a regional ip in Google Cloud?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have chosen "asia-northeast1" in the VPN machine and have reserved an External IP for my machine in "asia-northeast1". However it only gives me an America IP.

Is it possible to choose an IP from a region? Possibly in Japan?

Comment: Why do you believe the IP address is "an America IP"?

Comment: I use those whatsmyip tools to check the IP and shows that its an IP from google cloud in the US.

Comment: That doesn't tell you what country the IP address is in. Most of Google's IP addresses appear to be in the US,, but actually are elsewhere.

Comment: That's what I am trying to do, I want the IP address appear to be in the Japan. Just wondering if google cloud have this option to do so.

Comment: Why does the location of the corporate owner of the IP address matter to you? The servers will be in Japan, and the latency will be good for Japanese users as a result.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, all the external IP addresses used by Google Cloud Platform are from the Mountain View area, you can check the [region of your IP using this site](https://www.iplocation.net/). There is currently a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/72263361) in the works to allow IP addresses to match the region where the resource is being deployed.